# Saving recycler view scrolled state of fragment while using Navigation Architecture component

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-architecture-components, android-architecture-navigation

Problem Statement 
I have two Fragments :-
1. ProductListFragment (with RecylcerView implementation)
2. ProductDetailFragment

Using `NavController` class I'm navigating from ProductListFragment to ProductDetailFragment. But when I navigate back to ProductListFragment, it's showing List Items from top.

How can I save last scrolled position of RecyclerView, so that on navigation Back same state will be shown.

Also I don't want to save scrolled state when ProductListFragment is invoked from somewhere else except through popping to front from back stack.

Comment: If you can save your state when using 'Don't keep activities' and save your state when doing a configuration change (i.e., rotating your device), then it'll work just fine with Navigation.